# jsPDF doesn't show certain letters properly (ū)

Tags: character-encoding, jspdf

I am trying to create a PDF File to export using jsPDF library. In one of the lines I am trying to write a word that contains this 'ū' letter,

```
doc.text('Hūla', 20, 30);
```

However, when doing so the exported file doesn't contain this letter but instead it becomes
**'H k l a'** with spaces in between and a k instead of the ū.

What can I do in order to have this printed properly?

Comment: What exactly? `k` (U+006B,  *Latin Small Letter K*) or `K` (U+004B,  *Latin Capital Letter K*)?

Comment: @JosefZ it is k (U+006B, Latin Small Letter K)

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `'Hūla'.encode( 'utf-16-le').decode( 'cp1252')` returns `'H\x00k\x01l\x00a\x00'`, and I'd guess that *jsPDF* renders _unprintable_ control characters as _spaces_ in the latter string (`H␀k␁l␀a␀`) so you see **'H k l a '**.

Comment: On another platform, you can obtain **␀H␁k␀l␀a** instead as result from `'Hūla'.encode( 'utf-16-be').decode( 'cp1252')` (literally `'\x00H\x01k\x00l\x00a'`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use a font that supports this. I had to try multiple ones in order to get it working with this letter ū (it is not a specific language)

The font was Amiri. It also supported the Arabic font.